# Hidding comments by default for libreOffice?

Tags: apache-poi

I am generating a spreadsheet that users can fill data and upload again. And most column headers have comments with some minor rules (e.g. "Required").

The XLS files look great on Microsoft Excel and when imported on Google Docs. Where all the comments show up only on mouse over. But on LibreOffice, all the comments are visible from the start. Users can work around by selecting all cells and then view>comments. After that, the comments only show up when moused over, like on microsoft excel.

Is there any way to generate the XLS file in apache POI (XSS) in a way that the comments will be hidden in libreOffice too?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If used the example [Cell Comments - HSSF and XSSF](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellComments) my LibreOffice Version: 6.0.7.3 Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 also shows comment only on mouse over.

Comment: Thanks for checking! i have Version: 6.1.4.2 here. Will retest with the basic sample and update here.